# 404 Not Found error using Gunicorn/nginx only

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application that I am running via gunicorn and nginx on a Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have several routes files, all imported to `__init__.py`, and generally, working just fine. I added a new route to one of those files, which is basically, like all the others. The route works just fine locally on my development machine, but when I run that same code on the server, I get a 404 error.

I'm completely stumped.

Here's a snippet of the route file that's not working:

```
# This route works fine

@app.route('/admin/monthy_bad')
@login_required
def monthly_bad():
    monthly_bad = admin_utilities.monthly_bad(current_user.admin, current_user.domain_group_id)
    return render_template('monthly_bad.html', name=current_user.name, monthly_bad=monthly_bad)

# This route fails with 404 on the server, but not locally

@app.route('/domain_group/admin')
@login_required
def domain_group_admin():
    """
    Admin page for domain groups
    """
    no_domain_group = DomainGroup.query.filter_by(name='None').first_or_404()
    if current_user.domain_group_id == str(no_domain_group.id): # bump them
        flash("No Domains!")
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    else:
        return render_template('domain_group_admin.html', name=current_user.name, domain_group_id=current_user.domain_group_id)
```

I thought it might be a caching issue - but I have restarted the app several times (and even restarted the server.)

Any ideas on where to troubleshoot would be super helpful.

Comment: server shouls save some messages in log files and you should first check it - there you should get more information what can be the problem.

Comment: you use `first_or_404()` which may generate `404` when it can't find data in database - so you should check if you have correct data in database on server. You could also use `logging` module to safe information in log files - and this way you could check what you get from database. You can also split problem into smaller problem - first run this function only with `return "Hello World"` to check if it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

furas had the right answer, that was exactly the problem! The data I needed was missing on the server, and the `first_or_404()` returned the 404 error.